# import_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dataset' -

Tags: django, django-import-export

I have an issue when i want import data from an dataset with django import export user model ressource :

error :

```
import_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dataset'

Request Method:     GET

Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/home/
Django Version:     1.11.6
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

import_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dataset'

Exception Location:     /code/data_integration/tasks.py in MvmtjsHms, line 197
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.4.2
```

My ressource :

```
class MasterDossierResource(resources.ModelResource):
            class Meta:
                model = MasterDossier
                skip_unchanged = True
                report_skipped = False
                import_id_fields = ('indice',)
                exclude = ('id',)
                fields = ('indice', 'plt', 'ref_dossier',)
```

My model :

```
class MasterDossier(models.Model):
    indice = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    plt = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    ref_dossier = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

My code:

I use an existing file  for implemented my dataset depending to confitions, et i want to test dataset integration using ressource of my model

```
 def Mvmtjs(self,file, espace):

        import csv

        csvfile = open(file, 'r')
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=';')

        dataset = tablib.Dataset(headers=['indice', 'plt', 'ref_dossier_ath'])
       ]


        with open('tmp/edi/in/working/write_file.csv', "w+", encoding='mac_roman', newline='') as csv_file1:  


            next(reader)  # Skip header row.
            next(reader)  # Skip header row.

            for row in reader:


                if row[2] != "":

                    if espace == '1' or '2':

                    dataset.append( (
                               row[2],
                               row[0], 
                               row[2], 
                                  ))

        result = MasterDossierResource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True, raise_errors=True)
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure you are passing a valid dataset object into `import_data()` in your `tasks.py` ?

Comment: for the log the type is good : `dataset <dataset object>`
and dataset.dict 
`[{'indice': '505086',
  'plt': 'AIE',
  'ref_dossier': '505086'},
 {'indice': '505086',
  'plt': 'AIE',
  'ref_dossier_ath': '505086'},
 {'indice': '432656',
  'plt': 'ALB',
  'ref_dossier_': '432656'},...`

Comment: Obviously the error states that you are not passing a valid Dataset into `import_data()` - can you set a breakpoint in that method and inspect the object?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by inscpect the object ? I did this : `(Pdb) dataset
<dataset object>`

Comment: To move forwards, you'll have to identify what is being passed to `import_data()` (`tasks.py:197`), because the exception is telling you that it is not a valid `dataset` object.  The error is telling you that there is a problem, which you can only understand by inspecting exactly what is being passed into the method.  The error you are seeing is a low level error in python, so you'll need to work through the code to figure out what it is.

Comment: For me my dataset is correct, indeed i had tried with the sample of tablib's FAQ, and i have the same issue ... i had tried too to change `(dataset,...` to `(dataset=dataset` and this time i have an error about self missing. ps thx for pdb i had never use this befor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an error around my resources... I had forgotten to initialize my resources:

```
dossier_ressource = MasterdossierRessource()
result = dossier_ressource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True, raise_errors=True)
```